# ucanaccess exception UCAExc:::5.0.1 type not found or user lacks privilege: EXT_DATE_TIME

Tags: java, ms-access, netbeans, ucanaccess

I am getting this error when running a login screen. I'm really not sure what the issue is as I followed a tutorial, and for him it worked fine. Here is my code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null ; 
    ResultSet rs = null;

try{
Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\Morgan\\Documents\\Database1.accdb");
String sq1 = "select * from user_account where username = '"+ tfusr.getText() +"' and password = '"+ tfpwsd.getText() +"' ";
pst = con.prepareStatement(sq1);
rs = pst.executeQuery();
if(rs.next())
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Login successfull");
}
else {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "Login Failed");
}
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Here are my dependencies:

[image: dependencies]

Comment: Are you using a **JTextField** for your Password entry or is it a **JPasswordField**?

Comment: Its a jtext field and in the databse its a short text field

Comment: You're not using the `PreparedStatement` properly. Call `setString` on it, after getting rid of those quotes. Also use try-with-resources for your dB objects. As has been said, use a `JPasswordField` so your code would be `pst.setString(1, new String(pField.getPassword()):`

Comment: You should post the stack trace to see, where the Exception is produced. Could be a lib/db version mismatch, https://jackcess.sourceforge.io/apidocs/com/healthmarketscience/jackcess/DataType.html#EXT_DATE_TIME .

Comment: Update your question with a link to the tutorial you followed.

Comment: Since you are using JDK 1.8, what version of NetBeans are you using? If you are using any version more recent than 12.5 then that is the cause of your problem, because none of them support JDK 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably caused by *password* being a reserved word.

So, try:

```
String sq1 = "select * from user_account where username = '" + tfusr.getText() + "' and [password] = '" + tfpwsd.getText() + "'";
```

Comment: Tried this , still getting the same error

Comment: _password_ isn't a reserved word. See [Access reserved words](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2#__toc262648753)

Comment: @skomisa: Browse for many examples, ie [validate username and password in java and ms access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36531993/3527297).

Comment: If you think the question here is a duplicate of the one you linked to then you shouldn't have answered this question at all. Instead you should have voted to close it as a duplicate.